# htaccess redirect 301 ALL to HTTPS + WWW with Cloudflare ON

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, cloudflare

There are several questions about doing a redirect, but none of them worked for me.

I need all traffic to be redirected to https://www.kodden.com/

And my subdomains need to redirect to https://subdomain1.kodden.com.br/

My site runs on Wordpres 4.7.1 and uses Cloudflare, my host runs PHP 7.0.7 and Apache.

The best I could get was:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But give me a redirect loop error when I go to https://kodden.com or http://kodden.com.br (redirect to https://kodden.com.br and give me a redirect loop) when Cloudflare is enabled.

What is missing?

Thank you all!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

In CloudFlare make sure you have Crypto > SSL set to `Full` or `Full (strict)`. Otherwise CF will fetch the page over http, sending the 301 to your browser, which asks cf for the page, which will fetch the page over http, which.... and there is your endless loop!

[image]

Comment: I'm not a wiz at htaccess but I think the issue is with the W's. You're requiring www with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.`.  but then redirecting to the site without www. If you want the W's, then you have to enter them in the new url: `RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]`

Comment: Hello Jules, adding "www." on the last RewriteRule when I type www.site.com.br goes to www.www.site.com.br. Thanks.